# Closest point of a disc to a plane 3D

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

I have a disc in a 3D space , the disc is created with a vector ( two points) passing in its center and a diameter.

Now what I need is to find the closest point on the circumference of the disc to the xy plane.

Basically I need to find the lowest point on the disc (in z axis).

I would like to have an help on this.

Thank you

Comment: You need to describe your input data a little more carefully. The center in space and the length of the diameter don't determine the disk. A picture would help us. Note that if the diameter is greater than the height of the center the disc might cross the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your disc is centered at $\vec{c} = ( x_C, y_C, z_C)$, radius $r$, and unit normal (disc axis) $\hat{a} = ( x_A, y_A, z_A)$, with $\lVert \hat{a} \rVert = x_A^2 + y_A^2 + z_A^2 = 1$.

---

If we wanted to solve the points where the circumference intersects the $xy$ plane at $z = 0$ (or any $z$ value):

The points $\vec{p} = (x, y, z)$ on the circumference are at distance $r$ from the center of the disc,
$$\lVert \vec{p} - \vec{c} \rVert = r$$
and perpendicular to the axis of the disc,
$$\left( \vec{p} - \vec{c} \right) \cdot \hat{a} = 0$$
Using Cartesian coordinates, the above requirements give us a pair of equations,
$$\begin{cases}
(x - x_C)^2 + (y - y_C)^2 + (z - z_C)^2 = r^2 \\
(x - x_C) x_A + (y - y_C) y_A + (z - z_C) z_A = 0
\end{cases}$$
Substituting $z$, we can solve for $x$ and $y$. (Typically, we get two possible $x$ values, and two $y$ values, so we substitute each of the four combinations to the above equations and verify which points are true solutions.)

---

The point on the circumference that has the smallest $z$ coordinate, is in the same direction on the $xy$ plane from the center $\vec{c}$ as the axis $\hat{a}$, if the axis points towards positive $z$; i.e. $z_A \gt 0$.

If the axis is on the $xy$ plane, i.e. $z_A = 0$, then the disc is perpendicular to the $z$ axis, and the point with the smallest $z$ coordinate on the circumference is at $(x_C, y_C, z_C - r)$, and the point with the largest $z$ coordinate on the circumference is at $(x_C, y_C, z_C + r)$.

If the axis is parallel to the $z$ axis ($\hat{a} = (0, 0, 1)$), then the disc is on the $xy$ plane, and all points on the circumference have the same $z$ coordinate.

Let's assume the axis points towards the positive $z$ half-space, i.e. $z_A \gt 0$. (If not, just negate $x_A$, $y_A$, and $z_A$ in all occurrences below.)

If we were to rotate the coordinate system around the center $\vec{c}$ and $z$ axis, so that the disc unit normal $\hat{a}$ is on the $xz$ plane, and to positive $x$, we'd have a right-angled triangle,
[image: Right-angled triangle]
with the center of the disc at the right-angle vertex $\vec{c}$, one vertex at the end of the disc normal $\hat{a}$, and the third vertex at the point on the circumference having the smallest $z$ coordinate.

One way to see this is that the slope of the blue line marked $r$ with respect to the $xy$ plane is the same as the slope of the disc normal vector $\hat{a}$ with respect to the $z$ axis, $\sqrt{x_A^2 + y_A^2}$.

Thus, at distance $r$ from the center of the disc $\vec{c}$, the point on the circumference that has the smallest $z$ coordinate, has
$$z = z_C - r \sqrt{x_A^2 + y_A^2 }$$

We can solve $x$ and $y$ in similar fashion, noting that the slope this time is the inverse negative ($-1/\sqrt{x_A^2 + y_A^2}$) due to the right angle.

Also, the point on the circumference is in the same direction on the $xy$ plane as the disc unit normal $\hat{a}$ is, as mentioned earlier.

Therefore, with the assumptions that $\hat{a}$ is an unit vector, i.e.
$$x_A^2 + y_A^2 + z_A^2 = 1$$
and that it is on the positive $z$ halfspace, not parallel to the $z$ axis, nor parallel to the $xy$ plane, i.e.
$$0 \lt z_A \lt 1$$
we find
$$\begin{cases}
x = x_C + r \frac{x_A z_A }{\sqrt{x_A^2 + y_A^2}} \\
y = y_C + r \frac{y_A z_A}{\sqrt{x_A^2 + y_A^2}} \\
z = z_C - r \sqrt{x_A^2 + y_A^2 }
\end{cases}$$

I'm not particularly happy with this description of the solution; I think it could be stated much more clearly and concisely.  Good suggestions (in a comment) or edits to fix the language or clarify the explanations are more than welcome. (I did test a few thousand random cases numerically to verify the solutions, so I do trust the math. It's just that me fail English thus now.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to see if this works. I'm not an expert and most of the maths you wrote is kind of Arabs to me . I don't really understand what a normal is.

Comment: @ajtechnologies: Cut the disk out of a stiff paper or card. Push a toothpick through the center, so it stands straight out from the disk. The toothpick is the axis for the disk. If we consider the part of the toothpick that is on the "upside" of the card, that part is the "normal" for the disk. If you use a toothpick that will protrude exactly 1 unit from the card, that protruding part of the toothpick is the unit normal for the disk.

Comment: @ajtechnologies: If $\vec{c}$ is at the center of your disk, then $\vec{c} + \hat{a}$ is the point that is exactly one unit above the center of the disk. (Since $\hat{a}$ is the unit normal, or unit axis vector, it is not a point near the disk: it is a direction.) If $d$ is the diameter of the disk, then the radius $r$ is half that. And, as I mentioned in the answer, I already checked the math, numerically; now it is your turn to try to understand it, and then (and *only then*!) apply it. Feel free to ask if you don't understand some part of it; I can try to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I do have the center point of the disc (x,y,z) and I do have another point that is not at distance 1 from the center. But of course it points in the direction of the circle axis. So How can I calculate xa ya and za?

Comment: @ajtechnologies: Let's say the center of the disc is at $(x_C, y_C, z_C)$, and point $(x_H, y_H, z_H)$ is somewhere on the axis. First, calculate the non-unit normal; this is temporary, so I'll call it $(x_T, y_T, z_T)$: $$\begin{cases} x_T = x_H - x_C \\y_T = y_H - y_C\\z_T = z_T - z_C \end{cases}$$Find out its length (or norm),$$T = \sqrt{x_T^2 + y_T^2 + z_T^2}$$and finally normalize to unit length:$$\begin{cases}x_A = x_T / T = x_T / \sqrt{x_T^2 + y_T^2 + z_T^2}\\y_A = y_T / T\\z_A = z_T / T\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. i will try it in a couple of days because my PC broke up last week. Thank you again .

Comment: I've tested the code, it works like magic. thank you!